# Python interactive shell: how do I know what method gets used when I simply type the name of an object?

Tags: python, shell

When it is a string or a number it is clear, the respective are printed

A="this is a string"
B=3

```
A
this is a string
B
3
```

What if I have more complex objects ? I am asking because I am learning a module and

```
A.name 
B.name
```

results in one line (practically overwrites the previous input)
while

```
print (A.name)
print (B.name)
```

resutls in two separate lines (normal behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just put an object into the console, the `__repr__` method will be called and you'll see whatever that method returns. Printing explicitly uses `__str__`. `print` falls back to `__repr__` if there is no `__str__`.

Demo:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '__repr__'
...     def __str__(self):
...         return '__str__'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a
__repr__
>>> print(a)
__str__
>>> del A.__str__
>>> a
__repr__
>>> print(a)
__repr__
>>> del A.__repr__
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x7f4bdf0034a8>
>>> print(a)
<__main__.A object at 0x7f4bdf0034a8>
```

Comment: So I guess in my case that method (__repr__) is repsonsible for overwriting the previous output?

Comment: @MiniMe probably. You can always check with the `repr` builtin.